# Return derivative vector from odeint scipy function

Tags: python, numerical-modelling

I have the following function that I want to implement in scipy.integrate.odeint

```
def numericSolver(rv_,t,alpha=1.,gamma=1.):
    BVal = B_f(alpha,gamma,t) #this function returns a vector
    BdotVal = Bdot_f(alpha,gamma,t) #this function returns a vector
    matDynamics = np.array([[0.,1.,float(BdotVal[2]),0.,0.,0.],
            [0.,0.,0.,float(BVal[2]),0,-float(BVal[1])],
            [0.,0.,0.,1,0.,0.],
            [0.,-float(BVal[2]),0.,0.,0.,float(BVal[0])],
            [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.],
            [0.,float(BVal[1]),0.,-float(BVal[0]),0.,0.]])
    derivatives = matDynamics.dot(rv_) 
    return derivatives
```

In order to implement this function I call odeint as

```
solution = odeint(numericSolver,IC,t=t,args=(alpha,gamma))
```

where `IC` is the initial condition vector, `t` is the time vector of interest, and `alpha` and `gamma` are inputs for `numericSolver`.

For a more clear explanation, `derivatives` is the solution, $\dot{\vec{X}}$, to the equation

$
\dot{\vec{X}} = M \vec{X},
$

where $M$ is `matDynamics` and `rv_` is $\vec{X}$.

Is there a way that I can get odeint to return the values of `derivatives` at each value in `t`? Or is it best to calculate the derivatives values manually using the values returned in `solution`?